# changing variable values in classes in C++

Tags: c++

I seem to have an issue with changing the variables in classes with C++.

```
int main() {
ofstream file;
file.open("example.txt");

Job serverJob("Server", "FOH");
TimeSlot slot1(Time(12, 30), Time(12, 30), serverJob);

slot1.setEndTime(Time(20, 15));
slot1.setEmployee(Employee("Jacob", "Smith"));

Roster roster1 = Roster("051015");
roster1.addTimeSlot(slot1);

TimeSlot slot2(Time(20, 30), Time(22, 0), serverJob, Employee("John", "Doe"));
roster1.addTimeSlot(slot2);

file << "\n" + roster1.toString() << endl;


slot2.setEmployee(Employee("Michael", "Hepburn"));
file << "\n\n" + roster1.toString() << endl;


roster1.removeTimeSlot(slot2);
roster1.addTimeSlot(slot2);
file << "\n\n" + roster1.toString() << endl;

file.close();
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

Output:

> Date: 051015
>   Slot1: Start Time: 12:30, End Time: 20:15, Job Slot: Server(FOH), Employee Assigned: Jacob Smith
>   Slot2: Start Time: 20:30, End Time: 22:00, Job Slot: Server(FOH), Employee Assigned: John Doe
>
> Date: 051015
>   Slot1: Start Time: 12:30, End Time: 20:15, Job Slot: Server(FOH), Employee Assigned: Jacob Smith
>   Slot2: Start Time: 20:30, End Time: 22:00, Job Slot: Server(FOH), Employee Assigned: John Doe
>
> Date: 051015
>   Slot1: Start Time: 12:30, End Time: 20:15, Job Slot: Server(FOH), Employee Assigned: Jacob Smith
>   Slot2: Start Time: 20:30, End Time: 22:00, Job Slot: Server(FOH), Employee Assigned: Michael Hepburn

The Output on the second printout should read "Employee Assigned: Michael Hepburn" instead of the "John Doe".

I can't seem to figure out how to make the program recognize the change in the slot1.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What does addTimeSlot do? Does it copy the TimeSlot? (*which is the default in C++*)

Comment: You should provide the definition of the class TimeSlot in order to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Modified answer. In these lines:

```
TimeSlot slot2(Time(20, 30), Time(22, 0), serverJob, Employee("John", "Doe"));
roster1.addTimeSlot(slot2);

file << "\n" + roster1.toString() << endl;


slot2.setEmployee(Employee("Michael", "Hepburn"));
file << "\n\n" + roster1.toString() << endl;
```

You print out roster1 before adding the modified slot2 to it.

Comment: I'm actually printing out roster1 both times. slot1 and slot2 are members of a vector in roster1. when I modify slot2 it doesn't seem to modify the slot2 located in that vector.

I'm thinking it's a pointer/reference issue. I'm just now starting to tackle c++ after having used Java for some time.

Comment: Yes, but that is before you change the name.

Comment: I guess more specifically I'm trying to figure out how when I modify slot2, it modifies the slot2 in the roster without having to remove and re-add it.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Apologies. My guess is that the addTimeSlot copies the slot's data, not its reference. Then , when you modify the data, the copy you store in roster1 is unaffected. It looks like TimeSlot is a struct, rather than a pointer to a struct. It's impossible to tell without the class definitions.

Comment: Of course, coming from Java, you are probably quite familiar with these things.

Comment: I was looking to paste class definitions, but it would be too large on here, haha.

http://codepad.org/7oEQBOXl (TimeSlot.cpp)
http://codepad.org/Za64xIoS (Roster.cpp)

Comment: I'm going to delete this answer, because it is wrong. Besides, the real problem is, indeed, in the class definitions. You want to pass a reference to the timeSlot objects, rather than the objects themselves, as I said before. Something like `roster1.addTimeSlot(&slot2)` but then you will also have to adjust the code for Roster. A good place to start: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html

Comment: Rather, the answer isn't 'wrong', it's just not the answer you are seeking. You can make the code behave correctly by calling `roster1.addTimeSlot(slot2)` a second time, but that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that you change employee for the slot but do not set the new slot to the roster.

You need a reference as parameter to your addTimeSlot(); method.

So it's prototype should be something more like :

```
void Roster::addTimeSlot(TimeSlot &);
```

And i believe that should do the trick.